# Показать / скрыть комментарий

Tags: jquery, css, комментарии

```
var maxc = 75,
            crop = '<span class="crop"> [читать далее] </span>';
        $('.text').each(function(){
          var text = $(this),
              html = text.html();

              if (html.length >= 75) {
                    html_hide = '<span class="hide">' + html.substring(maxc) + '</span>',
                    html_show = '<span class="show">' + html.substring(0, maxc) + '</span>';
                    text.html(html_show + crop + html_hide);
              }

        });
        $('.crop').click(function() {
            $(this).parent('.text').addClass('more');
        });
```

осталось только нажать на какой-то текст, он открывается (это уже сделано), а вот как сделать что бы остальные закрылись

Comment: можно как-то показать/скрыть комментарий не сразу, а анимацией

Comment: @jashka 

    $('.crop').click(function() {
        $('.text').slideUp();
        $(this).parent('.text').slideDown();
    });

Comment: вот простите, но я не могу совместить ваш первый ответ, и вот этот комментарий в единый работающий код

прикол в том что этот код сворачивает полностью все, а нужно только то что скрыто под hide -> скрытый текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так перед добавлением элементу `.text` класс `more` сначала убирайте у всех элементов `.text` класс `more`:

```
$('.crop').click(function() {
    $('.text').removeClass('more');
    $(this).parent('.text').addClass('more');
});
```